# How to write Xcode plugins?

Tags: xcode, ide, plugins

Where can I find resource on how to write Xcode plugins? I don't want to write macros and project templates, but plugins that extend the IDE functionality like the ones that can be developed for Visual Studio - capable of displaying in their own window and accessing Xcode project data.

Comment: One more thing regarding bounty. I'm aware there is now public API, but using private API is note problem for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See following:
http://maxao.free.fr/xcode-plugin-interface/

Answer (score 2):

Xcode does not have a public plug-in API.

Comment: Not, actually, true.

Comment: Actually, it is true. I can say so definitively, as I work on Xcode.

Comment: It does now! Some (minimal) documentation is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xcodekit).

Comment: Usually “plug-ins” are thought of as in-process, in which sense my statement continues to be true. The Xcode Extensions mechanism is based on App Extensions, which is entirely out-of-process, as I explained in session 414 at WWDC 2016 when talking about how to create them. :)

Comment: @ChrisHanson Is there any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe more up-to-date: https://github.com/phausler/XcodeAPI

found via Regexident's answer on [Xcode 4 plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316921/xcode-4-plugin-development)

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Alcatraz](https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz)

And then open XCode -> Windows -> Package manager, search [XCode plugin](https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode-Plugin-Template) in Template tab.

Then you can start a new project with XCode plugin template in OSX category.