# Xcode 4 plugin development

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcode4

I've been looking all over the place but I can't find anything. Does anyone know how to create an Xcode 4 plugin?

Comment: A good source of examples is the Alcatraz package manager: http://mneorr.github.io/Alcatraz/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As far as I know **there is no official way to create Xcode 4 plugins** (just like there wasn't one for v3.x).

Here is an openradar on Xcode's lack of plugin support:

> Please support the ability for 3rd
>   parties to extend Xcode via a public
>   plugin API.  Aperture, Visual Studio,
>   Eclipse, TextMate and other
>   applications benefit from this
>   ability.  I would like to see more
>   advanced refactorings, code analysis
>   (think Resharper by Jetbrains) and
>   modeling.
>
> [**Provide plugin API for Xcode 4** (rdar://8622025)](http://openradar.appspot.com/8622025)

**Please dupe this if you want plugins**!

---

Edit: Just stumbled upon this:

> **[Cédric Luthi](http://eerolanguage.org/2011/05/example-code-xcode-4-current-line-highlighting/)**: 
>   "**Xcode 4 does support user-defined
>   plugins**, see [CLITool-InfoPlist](http://eerolanguage.org/2011/05/example-code-xcode-4-current-line-highlighting/)
>   for an example of a working Xcode 4
>   plugin. You just have to add
>   XC4Compatible (true) in the
>   Info.plist."

https://github.com/0xced/CLITool-InfoPlist

---

That being said these GitHub repos might be handy, too:

- [Xcode4 Plugin-API Documentation](https://github.com/phausler/XcodeAPI) (*link dead*)
- [Xcode Plugin Template](https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode-Plugin-Template) (*link updated*)

---

Further more [**mogenerator**](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator)'s Xmod plugin might be a good starting point.
*(Wasn't Xcode-4 compatible yet, last time I checked, though)*

Comment: @Radu: Just added a link to my answer in which **Cédric Luthi** (aka **0xced**) states that **it is in fact possible to build plugins** for Xcode 4.

Comment: @Regexident, I see. This lack of support is quite unfortunate. Thanks a lot for the links. Also, updated question, looking for an easier way.

Comment: This might probably be better fitted as a separate question. To keep this question on topic and an easy lookup on Xcode plugins for others to come.

Comment: @Radu: Thanks. Then this question should hereby be answered, I guess. ;) Mind to accept it? (Btw, I already posted to your follow-up question. Had some time to write up an answer for that one after all :P)

Comment: XC4Compatible solution works just fine! We updated our XcodeColors plugin for Xcode 4 finally: https://github.com/DeepIT/XcodeColors

Answer (score 7):

Best way to learn is to look at github plugin code (see long list below):

- Basically its a plugin bundle.
- No main.m No MainMenu.xib
- First class loaded by setting NSPrincipalClass in info.plist
- in its init: you register for AppKit notifications
- See the code samples
- some check the mainBundle app id to make sure this is XCode
- The XCode Editor window class is DVTSourceTextView
- Its a subclass of DVTSourceTextView :NSTextView : NSText
- so you can register to listen for its notifications for NSTextView or NSText
- such as NSTextViewWillChangeNotifyingTextViewNotification

Because its not an official standard I noticed each sample loads in different ways.

XCODE PLUGIN SAMPLES

compiled by either searching github/web for

```
'DVTSourceTextView'
```

This is the Xcode Editor window class name

or

Info-list key

```
'XC4Compatible'


https://github.com/omz/ColorSense-for-Xcode

https://github.com/ciaran/xcode-bracket-matcher
- uses a ruby parser run as pipe!

https://github.com/joshaber/WTFXcode
https://github.com/0xced/NoLastUpgradeCheck
http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/downloads/list
    see GTMXcode4Plugin
https://github.com/DeepIT/XcodeColors
https://github.com/0xced/CLITool-InfoPlist
https://github.com/sap-production/xcode-ide-maven-integration
https://github.com/ciaran/xcode-bracket-matcher
```

TO GET TO THE NSTextView that is the console

https://github.com/sap-production/xcode-ide-maven-integration

```
- (NSTextView *)findConsoleAndActivate {
    Class consoleTextViewClass = objc_getClass("IDEConsoleTextView");
    NSTextView *console = (NSTextView *)[self findView:consoleTextViewClass inView:NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow.contentView];

    if (console) {
        NSWindow *window = NSApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
        if ([window isKindOfClass:objc_getClass("IDEWorkspaceWindow")]) {
            if ([window.windowController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"IDEWorkspaceWindowController")]) {
                id editorArea = [window.windowController valueForKey:@"editorArea"];
                [editorArea performSelector:@selector(activateConsole:) withObject:self];
            }
        }
    }

    return console;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this new plugin: https://github.com/sap-production/xcode-ide-maven-integration. Maybe you can derive some concepts for your plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday [ColorSense for Xcode 4](https://github.com/omz/ColorSense-for-Xcode) was released on Github. Since the code is really compact spread over just 3 classes, I think you should take a look over there.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode does not have a public plug-in API.

This was the case with earlier versions, and is the case with Xcode 4 as well.

Comment: Any idea what the reason for this might be?

Comment: Apple doesn't comment on such things.

Answer (score -3):

No, Xcode doesn't support plugins, alternatively you may try AppCode, another IDE for iOS/MacOS, it does support plugins development.

Comment: That's obviously not true as there are plugins for Xcode available and you can easily write your own if you need.