# How can I change the mouse's i-beam cursor in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ide, mouse-cursor

I use a dark background when I code in xcode 5.0.2 and maybe I'm just getting old but it makes it really hard to see the cursor when hovering over text.

I tried the solution on this question:
[Changing the mouse's i-beam cursor in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738220/changing-the-mouses-i-beam-cursor-in-xcode-4)

but it had no effect unfortunately.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me, it was as per the post you referenced, at the location:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/DVTIbeamCursor.png
```

The issue I had however, was that the file had been named as:

DVTl (lowercase 'L'), rather than DVTI (uppercase 'I').

Comment: Hmmm maybe I was just looking in the wrong place. The folder I checked definitely had a file with a very different name. Thanks!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just to save someone from searching for that replacement TIFF file. It's here: http://www.dracoventions.com/images/external/TIbeam.tiff

Comment: Using Mac OS 10.11.2 and Xcode 7.2.1 the path/file was `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/DVTIbeamCursor.tif`.

Comment: I used this successfully about a week ago and now in Xcode 7.2 build 7C1002 the DVTIbeamCursor.tiff is gone... :/  Any ideas?

Comment: For Xcode 7.3, the Ibeam cursor seems to have been moved inside the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Assets.car` file. Check out https://github.com/egold/better-xcode-ibeam-cursor/issues/16

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working fix for Xcode 9 (mac Sierra 10.12.6), using Mousecape:

- Download Mousecape [here](https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/releases/tag/0.0.5)
- Download the cursor [here](https://gist.github.com/alpriest/1fb8ab2c7406c7520b147a30f3f99c6b). (this is the DVTIbeamCursor.tiff file built for Mousecape)
- Run Mousecape and import the cursor
- Apply the cursor

Unfortunately the modified cursor will be lost after a reboot. 
To fix that do the following:

- Right-click on the Mousecape app and select "Show package
  content"
- look for the .app file at: `Mousecape.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/com.alexzielenski.mousecloakhelper.app`
- Manually add this app to your login items and you'll be all set

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution you'll find by using the link that [@aldryd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036611/aldryd) provided in the comments to the answer. GitHub user [sokobania](https://github.com/sokobania) provides the following steps:

> **Step 1:**

Download ThemeEngine from: https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine

> **Step 2:**

Run ThemeEngine in Xcode and you may be presented with a few errors.

1. Failed to code sign "ThemeEngine".

   - **Just click Fix Issue**
2. Nullability specifier '_Nonnull' cannot be applied to non-pointer type 'NSString'; did you mean to apply the specifier to the pointer?

   - **Allow Xcode to Resolve**

> **Step 3:**

We'll need to remove some derived data from Embedded Binaries. Click your root **application > Targets > General > Embedded Binaries** and *remove* the top item:

[image]

> **Step 4:**

Run **ThemeEngine** and select "Open Document", you'll need to locate your **Assets.car** file in Xcode here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/
DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/R‌​esources/Assets.car
```

> **Step 5:**

Once loaded, find **DVTIbeamCursor** in the list and drag your IBeam of choice over Xcode's default Ibeam.

[image]

I like use the Ibeam provided by [@TheTC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026038/thetc):

[dracoventions.com/images/external/TIbeam.tiff](http://dracoventions.com/images/external/TIbeam.tiff)

> **Step 6:**

Select "**Save As...**" and overwrite Xcode's **Assets.car** file with the new file. I had to save the copy to my desktop and then drag the new Assets.car file into the Xcode folder to overwrite.

---

**Troubleshooting:**

I recently tried this solution and I wound up with a **bridging-header** issue. If that happens click your root **project > targets > Build Phases > Link Library With Binaries > Add ThemeKit**

Rebuild and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't been able to get this to work in xcode 8.  What I eventually ended up doing is just setting the background color in the editor to dark dark gray instead of black (#222222 or #111111) and it's helped tremendously.