# are there any XCode plugin's that help automate creating delegates?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, plugins, delegates

Just wondering if there is anything available (out of the box, or 3rd party add-on's) that speed up developing in Xcode via automating creation of some of the basic patterns...

the one in mind I'm thinking of is setting up inter-controller comms using a delegate, so automating the creation of a delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are addons for xcode (I did not remember now). I installed one time, but thought difficult to use.

But you can fix it using the "Code Snippet Library", so create a new one for your delegate and it can work.

See here how create a [new code snippet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic form:

```
@protocol SomeControllerDelegate;

@interface SomeController : UIViewController
{
   ...
   id <SomeControllerDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic) id <SomeControllerDelegate> delegate; // @synthesize delegate = _delegate;

@end

@protocol SomeControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) someControllerDidFinish: (SomeController *) controller;
- (void) someController: (SomeController *) controller didChangeObject: (id) object;

@end
```

Comment: Note that your answer illustrates how to implement delegates but that’s not what the question is about. The OP is asking if there is an Xcode plugin that automatically generates, for example, delegate protocols/properties/protocol conformance like the code in your answer.

Comment: There’s no public Xcode 4 plugin SDK but some people have developed plugins nonetheless. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316921/xcode-4-plugin-development/6316935#6316935)