# Installing xcode4 plugin(s)

Tags: xcode, macos

Would really like to get this plugin working, semi-colon completion would be nice.

There's also a plugin to close square brackets, but just for starters I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Now, I have 2 versions of XCode installed, 3 and 4, but I know that Developer directory is for 4 as XCode 3 installed to Developer3.2.6 folder.

I'm putting the plugin in the Harddisk -> Library -> Application Support -> Developer -> Shared -> XCode -> Plug-ins folder.

Note after the Application Support there was no Developer folder (there is a Developer folder in my ~Library folder, so I put in the plugin into Developer -> Shared -> Xcode(had to create/Plug-ins and still nothing.))

I'm wondering if this plugin or plugins in general won't work with Xcode 4.

Here's the plugin and an instruction page to install a plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/xcode-auto-assistant/

http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/04/install-an-xcode-plugin/

Comment: As far as I know, plugins are not supported in XCode 4.  [Here is a related question about that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316921/xcode-4-plugin-development).

Comment: thanks, don't know why this didn't turn up when I searched, looks like I'll be getting another JetBrains product soon.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not related to XCode 4, but i find it really useful when installing a plugin (uncrustify) in Xcode 5.

For me there was not either a Developer folder in my ~/Library/Application Support path, so I copied it also to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Plug-ins (had to create Plug-ins) with no success whatsoever.

My solution was creating then manually the path from ~/Library/Application Support on, getting something like: ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins. In this case it worked perfectly. So basically, as simple as if it does not exist, create it.