# Refactor Objective C property access from . syntax to [ ] syntax

Tags: objective-c, xcode, refactoring

Is there a way to refactor property access code from `.` syntax to `[ ]` syntax in XCode 4?

For example:

```
myController.someProperty = someObject;
```

to

```
[myController setSomeProperty: someObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

I fear there's no way to achieve this with "standard" Xcode.

If you really need that you may consider to create a [Xcode plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316921/xcode-4-plugin-development) (even if I didn't understand very well if you can officially create plugins or not), but I'm not sure if it worth the effort...

I think probably it'll be easier to create some script with awk/sed that blindly replace dot syntax with brackets syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am afraid a simple script will not be enough, as some dots (`.`) refers to structs, and not properties. An Xcode plugin is an option (just for fun :) )

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about that :) Well, it may still be a possibility if you are sure there are only `interface`s in your code, but of course we are narrowing a lot the field of possible applications.