# Does Xcode support plugins with 4.6?

Tags: xcode, plugins

I am looking at a few open source plugins, but does Xcode support that yet or is Apple still refusing to make it public?

Comment: and this question is related to [one of Nick's earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900193/how-to-check-for-right-click-in-project-navigator)

Comment: @michael, it seems you guys have bonded.:)

Comment: @Nick, try checking the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316921/xcode-4-plugin-development